# Yocto: getcap and setcap not found

Tags: linux, yocto

I have included libcap in the local.conf. Executing following command gives error in yocto

```
setcap cap_net_raw+ep ./src/ports/POSIX/OpENer
```

`-sh: setcap: command not found`

Distribution details

```
ID=fsl-imx-xwayland
NAME="NXP i.MX Release Distro"
VERSION="5.10-gatesgarth (gatesgarth)"
VERSION_ID=5.10-gatesgarth
PRETTY_NAME="NXP i.MX Release Distro 5.10-gatesgarth (gatesgarth)"
```

Comment: You've got 2 option: 1. libcap not installed. 2. libcap installed, but required call directly. Check your file system with: `find / -name "libcap"` got library files.

Comment: I have already added it in local.conf

IMAGE_INSTALL_append += " git gnupg cmake libcap libcap-dev libcap-dbg libcap-doc libcap-staticdev binutils"

Comment: ok, but did you check your file system with `find` commend? Maybe you have it in you're system, but useing required a full path.

Comment: Yes, checked in my file system as you mentioned earlier, but no luck.

Comment: Please attach full local.conf file.

Comment: Installed libcap and libcap-dev manually and it worked! 


still don't know why the following configuration is not working.

IMAGE_INSTALL_append += " git gnupg cmake libcap libcap-dev libcap-dbg libcap-doc libcap-staticdev binutils"